# How can I mock with jest multiple different responses when I'm using custom react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-hooks, mocking

I have a hook which is called three times in the code:

```
const [{ loading: loadingHook1, data: dataHook1 }, fetchHook1] =
useFetchHook();
const [{ loading: loadingHook2, data: dataHook2 }, fetchHook2] = useFetchHook();
const [{ loading: loadingHook3, data: dataHook3 }, fetchHook3] =
useFetchHook();
```

So I use promise all to execute each fetch for example:

```
Promise.all([fetchHookGender("/request/api", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
     ...body
    }),
  })...
])
```

In my test I'm mocking the hook but just for one result, so is printing the same result on the three calls, I'm doing this way:

```
jest.mock("../useFetchHook", () => ({
 useFetchHook: () => {...mockResponse}
}));
```

And with this I can get mocked data on my unit testings, but receiving the same result/data for each call I did on the code.

Is there a way I can return multiple and different results of the same custom hook?

Answer (score 1):

you can make a mock like:

```
const mockResponse: jest.Mock = jest.fn()
```

then have your mocked hook do this:

```
useFetchHook: () => {
   return mockResponse()
}
```

then in each test you can change what the mock returns like this:

```
mockResponse.mockImplementationOnce(() => false)
```